# Encoding 720p 29.97 fps video, options in Adobe Media Encoder are 23.976, 24 or 59.94 fps

Tags: framerate, premiere

A little confused here, I have a video file that's 720p @ 30.303 fps.

Working on it in Premiere Pro CC 2014 and ready to encode the file and the options I get for h.264 Blu-ray under frame rate are 23.976, 24 or 59.94 fps, no 29.97 fps.

What am I missing here?  I think I don't want to be choosing the frame rate that's double right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Blu-ray standard doesn't allow this framerate with this resolution.
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/622722

Your options are either upscale your resolution to 1080i/p or to change your framerate to 24fps.
The former will probably produces fewer artifacts.

Comment: Won't upscaling degrade the video quality though?

Comment: In a way yes but not necessarily that much. You might want to upscale to 1080i not not 1080p. 1080i is much closer to 720p due to interlacing.